# I want to print soap response to myTableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, web-services, soap

Hello I am new to Swift and SOAP, I m using http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx and got response as `posts` I want to print this `response` to  `myTableViewController` please help Thankyou
**Response**

```
{Country = ""GetCitiesByCountryResult = "<NEWDATASET><TABLE><COUNTRY>NEPAL</COUNTRY><CITY>BHAIRAWA AIRPORT</CITY></TABLE><TABLE><COUNTRY>NEPAL</COUNTRY><CITY>JUMLA</CITY></TABLE><TABLE><COUNTRY>NEPAL</COUNTRY><CITY>KATHMANDU AIRPORT</CITY></TABLE><TABLE><COUNTRY>NEPAL</COUNTRY><CITY>POKHARA AIRPORT</CITY></TABLE><TABLE><COUNTRY>NEPAL</COUNTRY><CITY>SIMRA AIRPORT</CITY></TABLE><TABLE><COUNTRY>NEPAL</COUNTRY><CITY>SURKHET</CITY></TABLE><TABLE><COUNTRY>NEPAL</COUNTRY><CITY>TAPLEJUNG</CITY></TABLE><TABLE><COUNTRY>NEPAL</COUNTRY><CITY>BIRATNAGAR AIRPORT</CITY></TABLE></NEWDATASET>";}
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
class ViewController:UIViewController,XMLParserDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate,NSURLConnectionDelegate, UITableViewDelegate  {

@IBOutlet var CountryName: UITextField!

var parser = XMLParser()
var posts = NSMutableArray()
var elements = NSMutableDictionary()
var element = NSString()
var title1 = NSMutableString()
var date = NSMutableString()
var xmlData = NSMutableData()

func beginParsing()
{
    posts = []
    parser = (XMLParser(data:xmlData as Data))
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()
    //tbData!.reloadData()
    for element in posts {
        print(element)
    }

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "myTableView", sender:posts)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    let guest = segue.destination as! myTableViewController

    guest.city = posts
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String])
{
    element = elementName as NSString

    if (elementName as NSString).isEqual(to: "GetCitiesByCountryResponse")
    {
        elements = NSMutableDictionary()
        elements = [:]
        title1 = NSMutableString()
        title1 = ""
        date = NSMutableString()
        date = ""
    }
}

func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String)
{
    let data = string.trimmingCharacters(in: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()

    let str = data.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)

    if element.isEqual(to: "GetCitiesByCountryResult") {

        title1.append(str)


    } else if element.isEqual(to: "Country") {
        date.append(str)
    }
}

 func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?)
{
    if (elementName as NSString).isEqual(to: "GetCitiesByCountryResponse") {
        if !title1.isEqual(nil) {
            elements.setObject(title1, forKey: "GetCitiesByCountryResult" as NSCopying)
        }
        if !date.isEqual(nil) {
            elements.setObject(date, forKey: "Country" as NSCopying)
        }

        posts.add(elements)
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func invoke(_ sender: Any) {

    let country = CountryName.text

    let is_SoapMessage  = String  (format :"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body><GetCitiesByCountry xmlns='http://www.webserviceX.NET'><CountryName>\(country!)</CountryName></GetCitiesByCountry></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>")

    let is_URL: String = "http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx"

    let lobj_Request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: is_URL)! as URL)
    let session = URLSession.shared

    lobj_Request.httpMethod = "POST"
    lobj_Request.httpBody = is_SoapMessage.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    lobj_Request.addValue("www.webservicex.net", forHTTPHeaderField: "Host")

    lobj_Request.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    lobj_Request.addValue(String (is_SoapMessage), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")

    lobj_Request.addValue("http://www.webserviceX.NET/GetCitiesByCountry", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")

    let task = session.dataTask(with: lobj_Request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        print("response = \(response)")




         let xmlData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)


        self.xmlData = NSMutableData(data: data!)

        print("Body: \(xmlData)")

        self.beginParsing()

       print("Status is = \(self.date)")

        if error != nil
        {
            print("Error: ")
        }

    })
    task.resume()

}

}
```

**myTableViewController.swift**

```
class myTableViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource , UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var city = NSMutableArray()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView!.reloadData()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int
{
    return city.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    var cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")!
    if(cell.isEqual(NSNull.self)) {
        cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("Cell", owner: self, options: nil)?[0] as! UITableViewCell;
    }

    cell.textLabel?.text = ((city.object(at: indexPath.row) as AnyObject).value(forKey:"title") as! NSString) as String
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = ((city.object(at: indexPath.row) as AnyObject).value(forKey:"date") as! NSString) as String

    return cell as UITableViewCell
}
```

Comment: Will your send demo ? If you dont mind, I will check it and return back to you with solution

Comment: oky Thankyou I am sending now

Comment: Ok got it, Will return back to you with solution

Comment: What do you actually want into your tableview means If you type india then all cities of india will dispayed into tableview, Like this ?

Comment: yes exactly what i want

Comment: I used to pass complete data through seague but I want to convert xmldata into json format, I am failed please forgive me. I can't solve your issue. I am still trying and let you know

Comment: Well, i used AFNetworking and XML to dictionary class, if you want me to create an example for u i will, but in objective -C. @viraRathod

Comment: @ViralRathod, where exactly are you facing trouble? Is your segue successful? were you not able to reload tableView Data?

Comment: @jecky Its completely fine. really appreciate your help

Comment: @KrishnaCA Thankyou for reply, the problem is cant pass my data to  myTableViewController. i  get response but cant print in table view

Comment: @ Aragunz Thankyou for your reply, I just started coding in ios Swift, but dont know objective -C

Comment: @ViralRathod, please check my answer and let me know if it works or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking your code, I found out that your problem is that you were not parsing your XML data correctly.

After getting the value for "GetCitiesByCountryResult", you can convert that into xml data and parse it again to get list of all cities as an array. After that, you can pass it to the viewcontroller for further results

```
let xmlArray = posts.value(forKey: "GetCitiesByCountryResult") as! [String]
let xmlString: String = xmlArray[0]

if let xml_Data:Data = xmlString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
    parser = XMLParser(data: xml_Data)
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()
}
```

Comment: Hello, Thankyou for Reply,  But its Got error  in `self.reloadData()`  `Value of type 'myTableViewController' has no member 'reloadData'`

Comment: @ KrishnaCA Nop Sorry error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: @ViralRathod, can you send me your demo? If you don't mind, I will check it and return back to you with solution

Comment: @ViralRathod, I solved your problem. Will reply back and modify the above answer to include the solution

Comment: @ViralRathod, I sent the modified project to your email. Please check it and let me know